# Binary Search Tree (wrapper)

Tags: data-structures, wrapper, binary-search-tree

I missed class last week so I am watching the online lecture (my professor records his lectures) and he keeps referring to a "wrapper".

I don't recall him explaining what a wrapper is. What does he mean by that? I googled it but to no avail. The language we are learning data structures in is C. Thank you!

Comment: a wrapper is exactly that: a wrapper.  It's a layer of software that (usually) simplifies accessing an algorithm or library. Also, google is a great tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A wrapper is usually some object or function that hides a full implementation behind an easier-to-use interface.  Typically, a wrapper object around a binary search tree would be an object that exports nice functions like "insert," "delete," and "lookup" without any of those functions taking in explicit node pointers.  That way, the binary search tree can be used without leaking the details of the representation to the client.

You sometimes also see the term "wrapper" used to represent any piece of software that sits atop some other software and simplifies it.  For example, some libraries for networking might be wrappers around the sockets API - they use sockets as an underlying representation, but don't expose that to clients.  That way, clients can use the easier library rather than concerning themselves with all the low-level details of the sockets API.  You also sometimes see C++ wrappers around C code that use C++ objects, which have constructors, destructors, encapsulation, etc., to simplify the C code.

Wrapper functions are sometimes used to make recursive functions easier to write.  In some cases, you might have a recursive function that takes in extra parameters in order to operate properly.  A wrapper function might just call the recursive function with the appropriate parameters.  That way, you can directly call the wrapper function rather than calling the recursive function, passing in a bunch of other parameters.

Hope this helps!